# How to calculate divergence of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

Could somebody explain the method used here to differentiate? I understand how to calculate divergence of simple functions, but the method above isn’t very clear. By the way, $x\in\mathbb R^3$, $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Please take the time to enter key parts of your question—in this case pretty much the entire question—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Your question is incomprehensible with images disabled. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}\nabla\cdot \left(\frac{x}{\|x\|^{2a}}  \right)&=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{x_i}{\|x\|^{2a}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left[\frac{1}{\|x\|^{2a}}-2ax_i\|x\|^{-2a-1}\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}  \right]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left[\frac{1}{\|x\|^{2a}} -2a\frac{x_i^2}{\|x\|^{2a+2}}  \right]\\
&=\frac{3}{\|x\|^{2a}}-2a\frac{\|x\|^2}{\|x\|^{2a+2}}\\
&= \frac{3-2a}{\|x\|^{2a}}
\end{align*}

Note that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\|x\|=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}=2x_1\frac{1}{2} (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=x_1\|x\|^{-1}=\frac{x_1}{\|x\|}$$

Comment: In the second line, where does $\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}$ come from? It looks like it comes from the chain rule, but can’t derive it.

Comment: @Loobear23 I added some details

Answer (score 1):

If $f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ is a scalar function, and $\mathbf{g}:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is a vector function, then we have
$$\nabla.(f\mathbf{g})=f\nabla.\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{g}.\nabla f$$
(you can verify this simply by writing out both sides in full).

Here we have $f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{1}{||x||^{2a}}=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-a}$ and $\mathbf{g}(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$.

So $\nabla.\mathbf{g}$ is just $3$, and I will let you work out $\nabla f$ for yourself.

It's true that the equation looks daunting when you first see it, but it's quite straightforward if you work it through.