# Calculate $\operatorname{div}\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|_{2}}\right)$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

with$$ x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $$
I am not sure how to approach this problem.
div is defined as the following, where F is an differentiable vector function:
$$\operatorname{div} F:=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial_{i} F_{i}$$

I thought about defining
$$u: x \mapsto \frac{1}{||x||_{2}}$$ and then using,
$$\operatorname{div}(u F)=\langle\operatorname{grad} u, F\rangle+u \operatorname{div} F$$
but I don't see how x can be an differentiable vector function.
I'd be very thankful for an approach.

Comment: $\partial_j (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n) = (0,0,\dots 1,\dots, 0)$ with the $1$ at position $j$, or if you prefer $\mathrm{grad}(x) = \mathrm{Id}$.

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful "https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3605172/523306"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, definitions: Let $\mathbf{X}=(x_1,...,x_n)$, let $\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{{x_i}^2}}$, and let $\hat{\mathbf{X}}=\frac{\mathbf{X}}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert}$.
We wish to show that
$$\nabla \boldsymbol{\cdot} \hat{\mathbf{X}}=\frac{n-1}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert}.$$
Well, using the quotient rule, it's clear that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{x_i}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert} = \frac{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert^2-{x_i}^2}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert^3}$$
Therefore,
$$\nabla \boldsymbol{\cdot} \hat{\mathbf{X}} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{x_i}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert^2-{x_i}^2}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert^3}}$$

$$=\frac{n-1}{\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert}.$$
Feel free to ask about anything you don't understand!

Comment: Thanks for the help! But where does the ^2 for $||x||$ come from?  Using the quotient rule, I'd get  $||x||^1 $

Comment: I multiplied the numerator and denominator by $\Vert\mathbf{X}\Vert$.

Comment: Oh I see. Had a mistake in my thinking, thanks :)